# IF cell contains, THEN return certain value with more values and return possibilities

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet with the following columns:
Column 1: contains text of the form "TS001", "TS002", "DR001", "MS002" etc.
The 2 letter in the beginning are a code for the manufacturer name, so for example "MS=Microsoft".
For the second column, I would like to have a formula that goes through the first column and searches for those letters, in order to then return the complete name of the manufacturer.

For example, it should look something like this:

| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| MS001 | Microsoft |
| TS002 | Tesco |
| DR001 | DR. Pepper |
| TS003 | Tesco |

Is something like that possible?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You need to share an sample sheet with the result required.

Comment: VBA and Google Apps Script, Google Sheets and Excel are two completely different frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "MS=Microsoft" it implies somewhere you have a table with that reference. For the purposes of the following example I created a sheet named `ReferenceTable` where column A contains the two letter code, and column B contains the name of the company. So it looks like this:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| MS | Microsoft |
| TS | Tesco |

And now in the main sheet in column B you would write the following formula:

> `=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(MID(A1:A,1,2),ReferenceTable!A1:B,2,FALSE))`

This will give you the name of the company, looked up from the reference table.
The array formula is there so that you only have to put this formula in cell B1, and assumes you will use the ReferenceTable sheet as a list; that way as you add records to Column A Column B is populated by the arrayformula in B1.

Answer (score -1):

I'd simply use a Reference Table and a VLOOKUP formula

If cell `B7` contains "**MS0001**"

the following formula will attempt to match just the first two letters again a reference table located in cells `O7:P9`

=VLOOKUP(MID(B7,1,2),O7:P9,2,FALSE)

and will return "**Microsoft**"  when it finds "**MS**"

Answer (score -2):

In order to achieve what you want, somewhere you need to have a list of the two letter codes and the corresponding company name.

As with all vba, there’s any number of ways to do this, but I would probably put the two letter code and company data into an array, then iterate through col1 to create the desired output for col2.

E.g below assumes the two letter code and company names are in col3 and col4 respectively, but you can change it to wherever they’re located.

```
Sub CompName()

Dim Cmpname () as string
Dim col1 as range, rng as range

Cmpname = range(range(“C1”), range(“D1048576”).end(xlup))
Set col1 = range(range(“A1”), range(“A1048576”).end(xlup))

For each rng in col1
     For i = lbound(Cmpname, 1) to ubound(Cmpname, 1)
         If left(rng, 2) = Cmpname(i, lbound(Cmpname, 2)) then
                rng.offset(0,1) = Cmpname(i, ubound(Cmpname, 2))
                Exit For
         End if
     Next
Next

End Sub
```

I’ve admittedly just written this on my phone and have not tested it, but hopefully there’s minimal mistakes.

Answer (score -2):

I just reread your question and realized that you may actually want a formula rather than vba code.

If this is correct, using an INDEX MATCH is probably your best bet.

In this example I’ll assume the same setup as described above - col3 has company codes and col4 has company name - and this formula can be inserted into cell B1:

=index(D:D,match(left(A1,2),C:C,0))

You can then just filldown for the rest of the entries in col2.

Again, done from memory without testing so hopefully got it right.